# Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\templa\v-includes\class.DAL.php on line 63

Tags: php

Have been trying all possible means to locate why it still showing fetal error but it keeps bouncing me back......
here is were am get the error

```
function getValue_where($table_name,$value,$row_value,$value_entered)
    {
        try{
            $query = $this->link->query("SELECT $value from $table_name where $row_value='$value_entered'");
            $query->execute();
            $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
            if($rowcount > 0){
                $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                return $result;
            }
            else{
                return $rowcount;
            }
        }
```

Here is the full snipet of the code................

```
<?php
//include class library of database connecton
include 'class.database.php';
class ManageContent_DAL
{
    public $link;

    //construct function
    function __construct()
    {
        $db_Connection = new dbConnection();
        $this->link = $db_Connection->connect();
        return $this->link;
    }


    function getValue($table_name,$value)
    {
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT $value from $table_name");
        $query->execute();
        $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
        if($rowcount > 0){
            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        }
        else{
            return $rowcount;
        }
    }

    function getValue_descending($table_name,$value)
    {
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT $value from $table_name ORDER BY `id` DESC");
        $query->execute();
        $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
        if($rowcount > 0){
            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        }
        else{
            return $rowcount;
        }
    }

    function getValue_distinct($table_name,$value)
    {
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT DISTINCT $value from $table_name");
        $query->execute();
        $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
        if($rowcount > 0){
            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        }
        else{
            return $rowcount;
        }
    }

    function getValue_where($table_name,$value,$row_value,$value_entered)
    {
        try{
            $query = $this->link->query("SELECT $value from $table_name where $row_value='$value_entered'");
            $query->execute();
            $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
            if($rowcount > 0){
                $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                return $result;
            }
            else{
                return $rowcount;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            throw "Result Not Found";
        }
    }

    function getValueWhere_descending($table_name,$value,$row_value,$value_entered)
    {
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT $value from $table_name where $row_value='$value_entered' ORDER BY `id` DESC");
        $query->execute();
        $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
        if($rowcount > 0){
            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        }
        else{
            return $rowcount;
        }
    }

    function getValue_twoCoditions($table_name,$value,$row_value1,$value_entered1,$row_value2,$value_entered2)
    {
        try{
            $query = $this->link->query("SELECT $value from $table_name where $row_value1='$value_entered1' AND $row_value2='$value_entered2'");
            $query->execute();
            $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
            if($rowcount > 0){
                $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                return $result;
            }
            else{
                return $rowcount;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            throw "Result Not Found";
        }
    }

    function getValue_twoCoditions_descending($table_name,$value,$row_value1,$value_entered1,$row_value2,$value_entered2)
    {
        try{
            $query = $this->link->query("SELECT $value from $table_name where $row_value1='$value_entered1' AND $row_value2='$value_entered2' ORDER BY `id` DESC");
            $query->execute();
            $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
            if($rowcount > 0){
                $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                return $result;
            }
            else{
                return $rowcount;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            throw "Result Not Found";
        }
    }

    //get all the latest aricles 
    function getValue_latest($table_name,$value)
    {
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT $value from $table_name pet ORDER BY `article_date` DESC");
        $query->execute();
        $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
        if($rowcount > 0){
            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        }
        else{
            return $rowcount;
        }
    }
    //get latest article according to the author
    function getValue_latest_where($table_name,$value,$row_value,$value_entered)
    {
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT $value from $table_name where $row_value='$value_entered' ORDER BY `article_date` DESC");
        $query->execute();
        $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
        if($rowcount > 0){
            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        }
        else{
            return $rowcount;
        }
    }

    //function for inserting member's details
    function insertMember($name,$email_id,$dob,$gender,$contact_no,$address,$city,$postal_code,$state,$country,
    $username,$password,$membership_id,$date,$expiration_date)
    {
        $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO `member_table`(`name`, `email_id`, `dob`, `gender`, `contact_no`,`address`, `city`, `postal_code`, `state`, `country`, `username`, `password`, `membership_id`, `date`, `expiration_date`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $values = array($name,$email_id,$dob,$gender,$contact_no,$address,$city,$postal_code,$state,$country,$username,$password,$membership_id,$date,$expiration_date);
        $query->execute($values);
        return $query->rowCount();
    }

    /*method for inserting member in mlm_info
    //Auth Dipanjan  
    */
    function insertMembershipId($membership_id,$date){
        $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO `mlm_info`(`membership_id`, `date`) VALUES (?,?)");
        $values = array($membership_id,$date);
        $query->execute($values);
        return $query->rowCount();
    }

    /*method for inserting withdrawal amount
    //Auth Dipanjan  
    */
    function insertWithdrawalAmount($membership_id,$withdraw_amount,$frozen_money,$withdraw_id,$date,$status){
        $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO `withdraw_log`(`membership_id`, `withdraw_amount`, `frozen_money`, `withdraw_order_id`, `date`, `status`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $values = array($membership_id,$withdraw_amount,$frozen_money,$withdraw_id,$date,$status);
        $query->execute($values);
        return $query->rowCount();
    }

    /*method for inserting information in money transfer log
    //Auth Dipanjan  
    */
    function insertDebitAmount($membership_id,$product_id,$quantity,$date,$amount,$system_balence,$frozen_money,$notes){
        $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO `money_transfer_log`
        (`membership_id`, `product_id`, `product_quantity`, `date`, `debit`, `system_balence`, `frozen_money`, `notes`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $values = array($membership_id,$product_id,$quantity,$date,$amount,$system_balence,$frozen_money,$notes);
        $query->execute($values);
        return $query->rowCount();
    }
    /*method for inserting information in money transfer log
    //Auth Dipanjan  
    */
    function insertCreditAmount($membership_id,$product_id,$quantity,$date,$amount,$system_balence,$frozen_money,$notes){
        $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO `money_transfer_log`
        (`membership_id`, `product_id`, `product_quantity`, `date`, `credit`, `system_balence`, `frozen_money`, `notes`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $values = array($membership_id,$product_id,$quantity,$date,$amount,$system_balence,$frozen_money,$notes);
        $query->execute($values);
        return $query->rowCount();
    }
    /*method for inserting information in purchase info table
    //Auth Dipanjan  
    */
    function insertPurchaseInfo($order_id,$product_id,$quantity,$date,$payment_method,$payment_status){
        $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO `purchase_info`(`order_id`, `product_id`, `quantity`, `date`, `payment_method`, `payment_status`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $values = array($order_id,$product_id,$quantity,$date,$payment_method,$payment_status);
        $query->execute($values);
        return $query->rowCount();
    }
    /*method for inserting information in purchase info table
    //Auth Dipanjan  
    */
    function insertPurchaseInfoPaypal($order_id,$product_id,$quantity,$date,$payment_method,$payment_request,$payment_status){
        $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO `purchase_info`(`order_id`, `product_id`, `quantity`, `date`, `payment_method`, `payment_request`, `payment_status`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $values = array($order_id,$product_id,$quantity,$date,$payment_method,$payment_request,$payment_status);
        $query->execute($values);
        return $query->rowCount();
    }

    /*method for inserting account information of member
    //Auth Dipanjan  
    */
    function insertAcDetails($membership_id,$ac_name,$ac_no,$bank,$branch,$ifsc,$status){
        $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO `member_account_details`(`membership_id`, `ac_name`, `ac_no`, `bank`, `branch`, `ifsc_code`, `status`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $values = array($membership_id,$ac_name,$ac_no,$bank,$branch,$ifsc,$status);
        $query->execute($values);
        return $query->rowCount();
    }

    //getting last value of a column
    function getLastValue($table_name,$column_name,$sorting_column){
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT $column_name FROM $table_name ORDER BY $sorting_column DESC LIMIT 1");
        $query->execute();
        $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
        if($rowcount > 0){
            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        }
        else{
            return $rowcount;
        }
    }

    //function for search functionality
    function getvalue_search($table_name,$value,$row_value,$value_entered)
    {
        //$value_entered = htmlentities($value_entered);
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT $value from $table_name WHERE (( $row_value LIKE '%".$value_entered."%') OR (`company_city` LIKE '%".$value_entered."%') OR (`company_name` LIKE '%".$value_entered."%')) AND (`status` = '1') AND (`end_date` >= CURDATE()) ORDER BY RAND()");
        $query->execute();
        $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
        if($rowcount > 0){
            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        }
        else{
            return $rowcount;
        }
    }
    //get ads according to email(username)
    function getValue_email($table_name,$value,$row_value,$value_entered)
    {
        //$value_entered = htmlentities($value_entered);
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT $value from $table_name WHERE $row_value LIKE '".$value_entered."'");
        $query->execute();
        $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
        if($rowcount > 0){
            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        }
        else{
            return $rowcount;
        }
    }
    //get submenus according to the position
    function getSubmenu_ordered($table_name,$value,$order)
    {
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT $value from $table_name HAVING $order > 0  ORDER BY $order ASC");
        $query->execute();
        $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
        if($rowcount > 0){
            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        }
        else{
            return $rowcount;
        }
    }
    //get vertical nav sorted by parent_id and position
    function getMenu_sorted($table_name,$value,$order,$value_parent)
    {
        $query = $this->link->query("SELECT $value from $table_name HAVING $order = $value_parent ORDER BY $order,`parent_id`,`position` ASC");
        $query->execute();
        $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
        if($rowcount > 0){
            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        }
        else{
            return $rowcount;
        }
    }

    // function to store user tracking results


    function insertTrackingValues($companyName,$browserName,$OS,$browserVersion,$date,$ip,$time){

        $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO `tracking`(`browserversion`, `os`, `browsername`, `ip`, `category`, `date`, `time`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $values = array($browserVersion,$OS,$browserName,$ip,$companyName,$date,$time);

        $query->execute($values);
    }
    //function for update of values
    function updateValue_email_owner($table_name,$column_name,$column_value,$email)
    {
        $query = $this->link->prepare("UPDATE `$table_name` SET `$column_name` = '$column_value' WHERE `owner_email` = '$email'");
        $query->execute();
        $count = $query->rowCount();
        return $count;
    }
    //function for update of values
    function updateValue_email_company($table_name,$column_name,$column_value,$email)
    {
        $query = $this->link->prepare("UPDATE `$table_name` SET `$column_name` = '$column_value' WHERE `company_name` = '$email'");
        $query->execute();
        $count = $query->rowCount();
        return $count;
    }

    /*
    - method for updating the values using where clause
    - auth: Dipanjan
    */
    function updateValueWhere($table_name,$update_column,$update_value,$column_name,$column_value)
    {
        $query = $this->link->prepare("UPDATE `$table_name` SET `$update_column`= '$update_value' WHERE `$column_name` = '$column_value'");
        $query->execute();
        $count = $query->rowCount();
        return $count;
    }

    /*
    - function to get the likely values of keyword
    - auth: Dipanjan
    */
    function getValue_likely($table_name,$value,$column_name,$keyword)
    {
        $query = $this->link->prepare("SELECT $value from $table_name WHERE $column_name LIKE '%$keyword%'");
        $query->execute();
        $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
        if($rowcount > 0){
            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        }
        else{
            return $rowcount;
        }
    }

    /*
    - function to get the likely values of keyword with descending
    - auth: Dipanjan
    */
    function getValue_likely_descending($table_name,$value,$column_name,$keyword)
    {
        $query = $this->link->prepare("SELECT $value from $table_name WHERE $column_name LIKE '%$keyword%' ORDER BY `id` DESC");
        $query->execute();
        $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
        if($rowcount > 0){
            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        }
        else{
            return $rowcount;
        }
    }

    /*
    - function to get the likely values of keyword
    - auth: Dipanjan
    */
    function getValue_latestDate($table_name,$value,$no)
    {
        $query = $this->link->prepare("SELECT $value from $table_name ORDER BY `date` DESC LIMIT $no");
        $query->execute();
        $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
        if($rowcount > 0){
            $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        }
        else{
            return $rowcount;
        }
    }

    /*method for inserting values to given table
    //Auth Dipanjan  
    */
    function insertValue($table_name,$column_name,$column_values){
        //declaring variables for preparing the query
        $column = "";
        $value = "";
        for($i=0;$i<count($column_name);$i++)
        {
            $column = $column."`".$column_name[$i]."`, ";
            $value = $value."?,"; 
        }
        //modifying the string for column name and values
        $column = substr($column,0,-2);
        $value = substr($value,0,-1);
        $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO `$table_name`($column) VALUES ($value)");
        $query->execute($column_values);
        return $query->rowCount();
    }



     /* ====== codes written by vasu ================== */

    /* insert the new address provided by the users at the time
     * of checkout
    */
    function insertAddress($userShippingAddress,$dataType,$deliveryStatus,$ipaddress,$orderid){

        if($dataType == 'olddata'){
            $wholeAddress = $userShippingAddress;
        }
        else if($dataType == 'newdata'){
            $wholeAddress = $userShippingAddress['f_name'].' '.$userShippingAddress['l_name'].
                            ', <br>'.$userShippingAddress['company_name'].','.$userShippingAddress['company_id'].
                            ', <br>'. $userShippingAddress['address_1'].'<br>'.$userShippingAddress['address_2'].
                            ','.$userShippingAddress['city'].'<br> pin:'.$userShippingAddress['p_code'].
                            ', <br>'. $userShippingAddress['state'].','.$userShippingAddress['country'];

            // this line takes the users or guest email if they are entering the new shipping address                               
            $email_id = $userShippingAddress['email_id'];
             }                 
       $date = date('Y-m-d');
       if(!isset($email_id))
       {
           $email_id = "";
       }
       //checks whether orderId session variable exists or not
       $query = $this->link->prepare("select * from `purchase_log` where order_id = '$orderid'");
        $query->execute(); 
       if($query->rowcount()!=1){
            $query = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO `purchase_log`(`shipping_address`,`date`,`delivery_status`,`ip_address`,`email_id`,`order_id`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)"); 
            $values = array($wholeAddress,$date,$deliveryStatus,$ipaddress,$email_id,$orderid);
            $query->execute($values);  
            echo $orderid;
            return $query->rowcount();  
       }
       else {
           $query = $this->link->prepare("UPDATE `purchase_log` SET `ip_address`='$ipaddress',`date`='$date',`delivery_status`=$deliveryStatus,`email_id`='$email_id',`shipping_address`='$wholeAddress' WHERE order_id='$orderid'");
           $query->execute();
           echo $orderid;
           return $query->rowcount();  

       }

     }

    function insertShipCon($orderId,$shipComment){
       $query = $this->link->prepare("UPDATE `purchase_log` SET `shipping_comments`='$shipComment' WHERE order_id = '$orderId'");
       $query->execute();
       return $query->rowcount();
    }

    function insertPaymentCon($orderId,$paymentMethod,$orderCom){
       $query = $this->link->prepare("UPDATE `purchase_log` SET `payment_method`='$paymentMethod',`order_comments`='$orderCom' WHERE order_id = '$orderId'");
       $query->execute();
       echo $orderId;
       return $query->rowcount();
    }

    function insertPayment($orderId,$totalPrice,$memberid,$allProducts){
       $query = $this->link->prepare("UPDATE `purchase_log` SET `product_id`='$allProducts',`membership_id`='$memberid', `price`='$totalPrice' WHERE order_id = '$orderId'");
       $query->execute();
       return $query->rowcount();

    }

    /*
     * to get the maxpick value of a particular product 
     */

    function getValueWhereIn($table_name,$value,$row_value,$valueList)
    {
        try{
            $query = $this->link->prepare("SELECT $value from $table_name where $row_value IN $valueList");

            $query->execute();
            $rowcount = $query->rowCount();
            if($rowcount > 0){
                $result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                return $result;
            }
            else{
                return $rowcount;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            throw "Result Not Found";
        }



    }

    /*
     * Insert 1 for activated user
     *  Auth vasu naman
    */
    function activateUser($membership_id,$email){
        $query = $this->link->prepare("UPDATE `member_table` SET `membership_validiation`=1 WHERE membership_id = '$membership_id'");
        $query->execute();
        return $query->rowCount();
    }



    /* ====== codes written by vasu end here ========== */
}
```

?>
have even check on the include still not working....
Hope you can help me

Comment: Your problem is   $this->link->query i guess. What is link ?And where is $this defined ?

Comment: thanks for answring me$this->link is defined under "class.database.php" which is the database connection

Comment: how are you defining this function `getValue_where` ?

Comment: Your query line is creating the problem. Check the flow of $this->link->query  and the variables passed in the function

Comment: One of the variables could empty